# UFT GetCellData function causes IE to crash on SAPTable object

Tags: internet-explorer, qtp, hp-uft, webdynpro

I am using HP UFT 11.52 on the SAP Web interface (Web Dynpro) over Internet Explorer 8.

I have a `SAPTable` object that I am trying to activate the 'GetCellData' function on it to get the value under the "ID Number" column of the first row but when activating the function it causes the IE to crash and recover itself.

That's the code:

```
Browser("Browser").Page("Page").Frame("searchDialog").SAPTable("ResultsTable").GetCellData(l, "ID Number")
```

I know the Web Dynpro support of the new UFT is kind of new but is there another way to workaround it so the IE won't crash when I'm using this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column name is not a unique identifier, so column number is used to access table cell data.
According to UFT User Manual object.GetCellData( row, column) arguments are long integers, the row and the column numbers where the cell is located.

Use GetCellData like this:

```
Browser("Browser").Page("Page").Frame("searchDialog").SAPTable("ResultsTable").GetCellData(1, 1)
Browser("Browser").Page("Page").Frame("searchDialog").SAPTable("ResultsTable").GetCellData(1, 2)
```